# How to enable CORS on node js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, cors

I am having a problem that I don't really understand. I have a `node js` server that server simple `index.html` page (This is actually angular). My server code looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
var port = 4000;
var path    = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('.'))
console.log(__dirname + '/.');

app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true
}));



app.get("/", function(res, req){
  req.sendFile(path.join('/index.html'));
});


app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0' , function(){                                                                                                                                
  console.log("listening on * "+ port);
});
```

I my html page, I have and angularjs service that is accessing `localhost:7000` and `socket.io` that is accessing `localhost:7000`. 
My service look like this :

```
if(param){
  $scope.isloading  = true;
  $http.post(
    'http://' + $location.host() +  ':7000/container', 
    { "method": "start", "nomber": param } , 
    {}
    ).then(function(err, data){
    console.log("No error : ");
    console.log(data);
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    $scope.isloading  = false;
    console.log("end Loading"  + $scope.isloading);
    }, function(err, data){
    $scope.isloading  = false;
    console.log("error  ");
   });
}
```

and the html call to socket.io is this :

```
  <script>var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7000');
  socket.on("news", function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });</script>
```

my problem is that I am unable to allow the `angular service` and `socket.io call` at the same time. I have installed [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) on chrome. when I enable it, socket.io don't work, but `service` works.[image]. When I disable it service don't work and `socket.io` does: [image]. Can you please help me to find a solution ?

**Update**
I have tried many of the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js). But they don't work for me.

Comment: I have tried all these solutions but none seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        var allowed = ['http://localhost:7000'].indexOf((origin || '').toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        callback(null, allowed);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message says:

> A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header when the credentials flag is true

Why don't you try setting your origin instead?

I would use the following middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4000");
    next();
});
```

This is assuming that the credentials flag is absolutely necessary.